# Why is the pointer typedef not used in std::vector::data()?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

In the API of std::vector there are some typedefs and many functions which return these typedefs.

e.g.

```
reference operator[](size_type n);
```

Where `reference` and `size_type` are typedefs.

There is a typedef of `pointer` which it gets from it's allocator template argument. Why is the function signature of `data()` like this:

```
T* data() noexcept;
```

Rather than:

```
pointer data() noexcept;
```

Is there some reasoning behind this? Also why is it `T*` rather than `value_type*`.

If you want to check it is section 23.3.6.4 of the standard I have.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason `data()` exists is to get a pointer to the underlying array inside the vector, so that (for example) you can pass it to APIs that work with pointers not iterators.

The `pointer` typedef is not necessarily a real pointer type, it is a typedef for `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::pointer` which could be some class type that behaves like a pointer (sometimes called a "fancy pointer").

For the default case, `std::vector<T>` is `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>`, and `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::pointer` is the same type as `T*`, so it makes no difference.

But for `std::vector<T, CustomAllocator<T>>` if `data()` returned a `pointer` you would not be able to pass it to a function expecting a `T*` unless `is_same<pointer, T*>::value` is true.

Comment: See also LWG issue [1312](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1312) (which is where this was changed)

Comment: I see, it's because the C interoperability it is there for would be broken if it returns `pointer `. As that's the reason for the function, this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Right, although it's not just C interoperability. There are C++ APIs that deal with raw pointers too.